# How to change the background color of the button of softkeyboard

Tags: android, background-color, android-softkeyboard

Can anybody say that how we can change the background color of softkeyboard? Is there any changes in `qwerty.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard background color can be changed in `input.xml` using `android:background`.

If you're wanting to change the background for individual keys and begin theming the keyboard, I suggest basing your keyboard off of AOSP, Cyanogenmod's, or something similar.  The sample keyboard isn't meant to be a fully-fledged keyboard, it's just a sample.  Things that you take for granted like multitouch, themes, and text prediction aren't available in it.

I've uploaded a keyboard base to my website.  You can download it at [lrAndroid](http://lrandroid.com/lintype.php).

Notice how the keyboard background and key background are defined in the `input.xml` files.